# Understanding Ruby's basic management utilities?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I'm new to Ruby and RVM, but I've managed to get both set up on my system by following a simple tutorial. In the tutorial, commands like

```
gem install rails
which gem
bundle install
```

are used, without much explanation of the Ruby management ecosystem. My confusion is where all these utility programs come from? 
I only installed ruby 1.9.3 and rvm, but somehow 'gem', 'which', and 'bundle' are executable programs in my path. How exactly did they get there and where can I read about the arguments they take and similar utilities I may not have discovered yet. There are no man-pages for them.

Finally, I believe rvm is analogous to virtualenv in Python and gem is analogous to pip?

Thanks for the help getting started.

Comment: Note: As Michael Kohl points out, there are indeed man pages for which.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby 1.9 the Rubygems package manager is included with standard Ruby, so that's where `gem` comes from. More info with `gem -h` or and http://guides.rubygems.org/.

`which` is a standard utility in unixoid systems and has nothing to do with Ruby (`man 1 which` for details).

`bundle` comes from [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/), which is a commonly used gem for managing an application's dependencies. You generally have to install this manually, unless RVM does that nowadays. `bundle -h` has more info for you.

Comment: RVM by default installs this gems: `bundler`, `rake`, `rvm`(extracted `/lib` from RVM) and `rubygems-bundler`([no more `bundle exec`](https://github.com/mpapis/rubygems-bundler))